# Given an undirected graph, find an orientation such that every vertex has out-degree at least 3

Tags: algorithms, graphs, discrete-mathematics, network-flow, directed-graphs

> Given an undirected graph $G=(V,E)$, describe an algorithm that computes an orientation of $E$ such that each vertex has out-degree at least 3.

I know how to check if a vertex $v$ has at least $k$ edge-disjoint paths to any other vertex (using Ford-Fulkerson), so I thought I may use that for $k=3$.

Would appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $G=(V,E)$, create a directed bipartite graph $H=(V+E, F)$ where there is an edge $(v,e) \in F$ iff $v \in V$ is an endpoint of $e \in E$. All these edges have capacity $1$.

Augment $H$ as follows: add two additional vertices $s$ and $t$; for each $v \in V$ add an edge $(s,v)$ with capacity $3$; for each $e \in E$ add the edge $(e, t)$ with capacity $1$.

Compute a maximum flow $\phi$ from $s$ to $t$ in the augmented version of $H$.
Your problem admits a solution if and only if the amount of flow $|\phi|$ is $3|V|$.

To see this, first observe that $3|V|$ is an upper bound on $|\phi|$. Then suppose that there exists a feasible orientation $\mathcal{O}$ and look at any partial orientation $\mathcal{O}'$ in which each vertex $v$ has **exactly** three outgoing edges.
A flow $\phi$ such that $|\phi|=3|V|$ is obtained by sending one unit of flow across each edge $(v,e) \in F$ such that $e$ is oriented away from $v$ in $\mathcal{O}'$, the flow across each edge $(s,v)$ is $3$, and the flow across $(e,t)$ is 1 if $e$ is oriented in $\mathcal{O}'$ and $0$ otherwise.

Suppose now that there is a flow $\phi$ such that $|\phi|=3|V|$. W.l.o.g., $\phi$ is integral. A feasible orientation is obtained by orienting each edge $e \in E$ away from the (at most one) endpoint $v$ of $e$ for which $\phi(v,e)=1$. If no such endpoint exists, then $e$ can be oriented arbitrarily. Notice that this procedure is constructive and immediately yields an algorithm for your problem.